# How to add elements in a list if they are in increasing order in a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

I am practicing python questions and came across this question where I have to add elements in a list if they are in increasing order and store them in a list.

For example:

```py
my_list = [2,223,6,4,10,12,15]
```

From 2 to 223, the list is increasing and then from 223 to 6, it is decreasing. Thus, the sum is 2+223=225.

From 223 to 6, 6 to 4 the list is decreasing and from 4 to 10, 10 to 12, 12 to 15 it is increasing, so sum is 4+10+12+15=41.

So, my `sum_list` will be `[225,41]`.

The code I tried:

```
list1 = [2,223,6,4,10,12,15]
current_el = list1[0]
suml=list()
sum1=current_el
for i in list1[list1.index(current_el)+1:]:
    while current_el < i:
        print(i)
        sum1=sum1+i
        current_el = list1[list1.index(current_el)+1]
        print(current_el)
        suml.append(sum1)
        
print(suml)
```

Comment: what about 6? what's logic behind ignoring

Comment: From 223 to 6 the number is decreasing.. And from 6 to 4 also it is decreasing..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is way simpler:

```py
numbers = [2, 223, 6, 4, 10, 12, 15]
accumulated = []
for i in range(1, len(numbers)):
    if numbers[i] > numbers[i-1]:
        if i == 1 or numbers[i-1] <= numbers[i-2]:
            accumulated.append(numbers[i-1])
        accumulated[-1] += numbers[i]
```

With `if numbers[i] > numbers[i-1]` we check if a number is greater than the previous (increasing) and with `accumulated[-1] += numbers[i]` we add that number to the last accumulated value. Now we are only missing the logic to create a new element in the accumulated list, and this is when we find a number that is greater than the previous but the previous iteration didn't pass this condition or if there are no previous pair that we can check.

Another different solution more similar to the one you were trying would be doing this in two steps. The first step would create a list of lists with numbers grouped by ascending groups. Then you discard those groups of a single member (you are not considering 6 as an ascending group) and then you add the groups together.

```py
numbers = [2, 223, 6, 4, 10, 12, 15]
groups = [[2]]
for number in numbers[1:]:
    if number > groups[-1][-1]:
        groups[-1].append(number)
    else:
        groups.append([number])
accumulated = []
for group in groups:
    if len(group) == 1:
        continue
    accumulated.append(sum(group))
```

Comment: Thank you.. The first solution you provided is great.. I Did not think it that way